# Convert Flightradar24 API into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe

I've tried to convert flightradar24api, which gives a list of airlines, into a pandas data frame without succeed. So this is what i've done:

```
    import flightradar24
    import pandas as pd
    
    fr = flightradar24.Api()
    airlines = fr.get_airlines()
    items = airlines.items()
    list_items = list(items)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_items)
    
    print(airlines)
    print(df.head())
```

And this was the result:

```
      0                                        1
0  version                                         1594656446
1     rows  [{'Name': '21 Air', 'Code': '2I', 'ICAO': 'CSB...
```

That being said, could you please help me convert flightradar24 api into a pandas dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
fr = flightradar24.Api()
airlines = fr.get_airlines()

df = pd.json_normalize(airlines['rows'])
print(df)


                        Name Code ICAO
0                     21 Air   2I  CSB
1                40-Mile Air   Q5  MLA
2                      9 Air   AQ  JYH
3                    ABX Air   GB  ABX
4     ACE Belgium Freighters   X7  FRH
...                      ...  ...  ...
1337         Zambian Airways   Q3  MBN
1338                  Zanair   B4  TAN
1339          Zimex Aviation   XM  IMX
1340                  ZIPAIR   ZG  TZP
1341                   Zorex       ORZ
```

Comment: Perfect Solution. Thank yo so much NYC Coder!